# Does Health.app intelligently count step from multiple sources?

Tags: ios, health.app

I recently bought an external tracker to track various activity and I wonder, whether I should disable tracking on my iPhone?

E.g. let's say my tracker reports that I made 1000 steps and my iPhone reports that I made 850 steps within same period (carried both devices together). What will be the result score?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See answer in [this thread](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/147546/how-does-healthkit-resolve-recording-of-the-same-activity-by-multiple-sources), and official Apple KB item [here](https://support.apple.com/en-us/ht204351).

Comment: If an answer is the same as an answer to another question then you should flag or vote the question as a duplicate not just give a link